# Installing leiningen 2 on Ubuntu

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have followed the instructions here:

[leiningen.org](http://leiningen.org/)

To install from the lein script. I now have:

`~/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.4.3-standalone.jar`

How do I now run leiningen? The instructions are not clear.

Comment: you have step-by-step instructions [here](http://leiningen.org/#install)

Comment: thanks, I have followed those instructions step-by-step. However, when I run 'lein' I get nothing

Comment: do you have lein script in your PATH?

Comment: no, I deleted it after it downloaded the self-install.. I assumed it was just the download script

Comment: No, you still need it. The script is the entry point to everything leiningen.

Comment: I did the same thing!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting this as it might help other users.

Follow the [install instructions](http://leiningen.org/#install).

Please make sure the leiningen script that the install instructions is on your executable `PATH`.

The script is the entry point to leiningen commands, so it's still needed after the downloads are complete.

It takes care of setting up environmental variables, paths and everything else required to run leiningen, so you can use

```
lein <command>
```

instead of

```
java -cp <whatever>:~/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.4.3-standalone.jar ... clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main <command>
```

Answer (score 34):

On ubuntu, its quite easy. Download executable file, make it executable and place it in system path.

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein
$ chmod +x lein
$ sudo mv lein /usr/local/bin
```

You can also move it any directory which is in system path.

```
$ lein -v
Leiningen 2.6.1 on Java 1.8.0_77 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Comment: Or I could just do `sudo apt install leiningen `

Answer (score 1):

I got the same doubt. Solved it. By following the instructions everything will be set for you. Next run the previously used script lein.sh in bin for creating projects as below.

suppose ~/bin/lein.sh is your script location ,then

```
$ ~/bin/lein.sh new test-project
$ ~/bin/lein.sh --help
```

It will create the project in your bin folder it self.If you wish to access that lein.sh globally then include it in $PATH.

Comment: // , Where do you get `~/bin/lein.sh` in the first place? This answer raises more questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux distribution you can just download the leiningen script and move it to your /bin  folder. Once you've done that you can execute lein command and it will be installed for you. 
So from your terminal you can run:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein > ~/lein
```

to download lein script to your root path. Then you set it as executable and move to your /bin folder

```
$ chmod x+a lein
$ sudo mv ~/lein /bin
$ lein
```

After you run the command lein from anywhere on your terminal the lein script will install leininge for your and you'll be able to use it normally.